# Peticiones Http en ionic

Tags: api, ionic3

Quiero mostrar una lista de productos haciendo un llamado a una api que me retorna el json. pero a mi parece la respuesta llega algo tarde, después de que la app arranque y supongo que es por eso que no se me pinta
.-

Mi cogigo de peticion:

```
getPromociones(){

      var url = "x";

      return this.http.get(url).subscribe(
         (data)=>{
            this.data = data['Promociones'];            
            for(var i = 0; i <this.data.length; i++){
                  //console.log('contador'+ i +' '+JSON.stringify(this.data[i]['Titulo']));
                  this.itemsdata[i] = {
                     "id":this.data[i]['IdPromocion'],
                     "title":this.data[i]['Titulo'],
                     "description":this.data[i]['Descripcion'],
                     "image":this.data[i]['Url'],
                     "imageAlt":"avatar",
                     "icon":"icon-heart-outline",
                     "duration":"3:42"
                  }
            }

            this.data2={
               "headerImage":"assets/images/background/14.jpg",
                        "toolBarTitle":"Player",
                        "title":"Promociones",
                        "iconLike":"icon-thumb-up",
                        "iconFavorite":"icon-heart",
                        "iconShare":"icon-share-variant",
                        "iconCar":"icon-cart-arrow-down",
                        "iconCarPlus":"icon-cart-plus",
                        "iconSkipPrevious":"icon-skip-previous",
                        "iconPlay":"icon-play",
                        "iconSkipNext":"icon-skip-next",
                        "items":this.itemsdata
            };

            this.getDataForLayout1(this.data2);
         },error=>{
            console.error("error en la peticione");
         });

    }



    getDataForLayout1 = (data): any => {
         console.log('json '+JSON.stringify(data));
         return data;
}
```

la primera vez llega asi :

```
json undefined
```

ya segundos despues si llega lo muestra en consola pero no en la lista de la app. llega asi:

```
json {"headerImage":"assets/images/background/14.jpg","toolBarTitle":"Player","title":"Promociones","iconLike":"icon-thumb-up","iconFavorite":"icon-heart","iconShare":"icon-share-variant","iconCar":"icon-cart-arrow-down","iconCarPlus":"icon-cart-plus","iconSkipPrevious":"icon-skip-previous","iconPlay":"icon-play","iconSkipNext":"icon-skip-next","items":[{"id":61,"title":"ASEPXIA CONTROL PUNTOS NEGROS","description":"30% Descuento Precio Sugerido $99,90","image":"https://fefara.blob.core.windows.net:443/tds-demo/promociones/Promociones Julio-24.jpg","imageAlt":"avatar","icon":"icon-heart-outline","duration":"3:42"},{"id":62,"title":"BENGUE SIN OLOR 35 GR GEL","description":"30% Descuento Precio Sugerido $129","image":"https://fefara.blob.core.windows.net:443/tds-demo/promociones/Promociones Julio-30.jpg","imageAlt":"avatar","icon":"icon-heart-outline","duration":"3:42"},{"id":63,"title":"CICATRICURE ARRUGAS 60 GR CRE","description":"30% Descuento Precio Sugerido $268","image":"https://fefara.blob.core.windows.net:443/tds-demo/promociones/Promociones Julio-26.jpg","imageAlt":"avatar","icon":"icon-heart-outline","duration":"3:42"},{"id":64,"title":"DERMAGLOS CREMA 200 GR.","description":"30% Desc. Precio Sugerido $340","image":"https://fefara.blob.core.windows.net:443/tds-demo/promociones/Promociones Julio-36.jpg","imageAlt":"avatar","icon":"icon-heart-outline","duration":"3:42"},{"id":65,"title":"Promo sin grupo!","description":"promo","image":"https://fefara.blob.core.windows.net:443/tds-demo/promociones/Imagen no disponible.jpg","imageAlt":"avatar","icon":"icon-heart-outline","duration":"3:42"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar una `promise`, esto es un bloque de código que al ser llamado (de forma asíncrona) devuelve una confirmación o un error. Puedes leer más acerca de las promesas en javascript (válido tambien para typescript con ionic 3) en el siguiente enlace: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise

volviendo a tu ejemplo deberías hacer algo asi:

```
getPromociones(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(url).subscribe(res => {
         resolve(res); //devolvemos la respuesta de la llamada http
      }, (err) => {
         reject(err); //devolvemos el error si se diera
      });             
    })
}
```

y la llamada al método sería algo así:

```
getPromociones().then(
    res => {
      console.log(res);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    }
);
```