# Peticiones http en Ionic #3

Tags: http, ionic3

Tengo una confusion tremenda. 
tengo mi funcion perfectamente

```
getPromociones(id:any){

      //
      var url = "https:/xxx/promociones/ObtenerPromociones?IdCategoria="+id;
      return this.http.get(url).subscribe(
         (data)=>{
            this.itemsdata=[];
            this.data1 = data['Promociones'];            
            for(var i = 0; i <this.data1.length; i++){
                  //console.log('contador'+ i +' '+JSON.stringify(this.data[i]['Titulo']));
                  this.itemsdata[i] = {
                     "id":this.data1[i]['IdPromocion'],
                     "title":this.data1[i]['Titulo'],
                     "description":this.data1[i]['Descripcion'],
                     "image":this.data1[i]['Url'],
                     "precioUnitario":this.data1[i]['PrecioUnitario'],
                     "precioPromo":this.data1[i]['PrecioPromocional'],
                     "imageAlt":"avatar",
                     "icon":"icon-heart-outline",
                     "duration":this.data1[i]['PorcentajeDescuento']
                  }
            }
            this.data2={"headerImage":"assets/images/background/14.jpg",
            "toolBarTitle":"Product",
            "title":"Super discount",
            "description":"50% OFF",
            "iconLike":"icon-thumb-up",
            "iconCar":"icon-cart-arrow-down",
            "iconFavorite":"icon-heart",
            "iconShare":"icon-share-variant",
            "items":this.itemsdata

            }
            //this.toastCtrl.presentToast(JSON.stringify(this.data2));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data2));

         },error=>{
            console.error("error en la peticione");
         });


    }
```

cuando la prueba en mi computadora local todo excelente. El Problema esta en que cuando genero la apk, en el telefono no me sale nada y ya mostre un alerta y la peticion llega vacia..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya me estoy volviendo loco. gracias al cliente

Comment: Tal vez pueda ser porque no se alcanza a ejecutar la función cuando abres la app, entonces este proceso no es sincrono. Revisa este post tal vez te sirva https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143810/peticiones-http-en-ionic

Comment: tengo otras vistas con cas las mismas funciones. y toda la demas aplicacion funciona bien. es estrictamente esta peticion a esta url que no trae nada en el telefono.. gracias revisare el link.

Comment: tengo otras vistas con cas las mismas funciones. y toda la demas aplicacion funciona bien. es estrictamente esta peticion a esta url que no trae nada en el telefono.. gracias revisare el link.

Comment: Esta vista es la principal?

Comment: jejeje bro el link que me pasaste es una pregunta mia tambien. fijaate.. heeee no es una vista distinta a la principal o sea se ejecuta con un click

Comment: jaja cierto, ahora que lo dices, revisaste los permisos en la aplicación para hacer llamas http y https?

Comment: si claro . como te dije antes. las demas peticiones salen bien. la unica que no me sale la de esta url.. es una locura hermano. estoy al borde del colapso

Comment: Donde haces la llamada a tu función, puedes colocar ese código? Y revisa ahora este post, sirve que te este faltando algo. https://reviblog.net/2017/06/19/tutorial-de-ionic-comunicaciones-http-api-rest/

Comment: constructor( private http: HttpClient,
                 public navCtrl: NavController,
                 private toastCtrl: ToastService,
                public para: ParallaxService) {
                console.log('he iniciado :D');
                this.getPromociones(0);
                this.getCategoria(); }

Answer (score 0):

```
getPromociones(id:any){

      //
      var url = "http:/xxx/promociones/ObtenerPromociones?IdCategoria="+id;
      return this.http.get(url).subscribe(
         (data)=>{
            this.itemsdata=[];
            this.data1 = data['Promociones'];            
            for(var i = 0; i <this.data1.length; i++){
                  //console.log('contador'+ i +' '+JSON.stringify(this.data[i]['Titulo']));
                  this.itemsdata[i] = {
                     "id":this.data1[i]['IdPromocion'],
                     "title":this.data1[i]['Titulo'],
                     "description":this.data1[i]['Descripcion'],
                     "image":this.data1[i]['Url'],
                     "precioUnitario":this.data1[i]['PrecioUnitario'],
                     "precioPromo":this.data1[i]['PrecioPromocional'],
                     "imageAlt":"avatar",
                     "icon":"icon-heart-outline",
                     "duration":this.data1[i]['PorcentajeDescuento']
                  }
            }
            this.data2={"headerImage":"assets/images/background/14.jpg",
            "toolBarTitle":"Product",
            "title":"Super discount",
            "description":"50% OFF",
            "iconLike":"icon-thumb-up",
            "iconCar":"icon-cart-arrow-down",
            "iconFavorite":"icon-heart",
            "iconShare":"icon-share-variant",
            "items":this.itemsdata

            }
            //this.toastCtrl.presentToast(JSON.stringify(this.data2));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data2));

         },error=>{
            console.error("error en la peticione");
         });


    }
```

La solucion era facil pero algo extraña.. solo cambie la url de "https:// a "http://" . en la web las dos formas funcionan, pero en el telefono android 4.4 solo traia las peticiones iniciadas con "http" sin la (s). lo cual es raro por que tengo otras vistas con "https" y igual funciona.. pero esa fue la solucion